# Show the selected value everytime in the dropdown list

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

I need to display the selected category value displayed all the time. I have a list of category values and adding it to drop-down list from an array.

```
<form action="#" method="post"> 
    <select name="dropDown" id="drop_down_id">
        <option value=""> Select CATEGORY</option>

<?php
    foreach($decoded as $key => $value ){  
foreach($value as $key1 => $value1 ){
?>  <option value="<?php echo $value1;?>"><?php echo $value1;?></option><?php   
}
}
?>
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use post for form so you can use POST to know last selected:

```
$dropDown=htmlentities($_POST['dropDown'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

And then just simple make if statement and its done:

```
if($dropDown==$value1){$selected='selected';}else{$selected=null;}
```

result:

```
<?php
$dropDown=htmlentities($_POST['dropDown'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");    
?>  
<form action="#" method="post"> 
    <select name="dropDown" id="drop_down_id">
        <option value=""> Select CATEGORY</option>

        <?php
            foreach($decoded as $key => $value ){  
                foreach($value as $key1 => $value1 ){
                    if($dropDown==$value1){$selected='selected';}else{$selected=null;}
                    echo '<option value="'.$value1.'" '.$selected.'>'.$value1.'</option>';  
                }
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

You can also store it in PHP SESSSION http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php